# Unix, split file into chunks of max N bytes, keeping complete lines

Tags: bash, unix, split

I'd like to split a file into chunks of maximum N bytes, while keeping complete lines.

Something like the following breaks up first and last lines of each chunk on exact byte boundries.

```
split -b 100m -d data.tsv data.tsv.
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sounds like a job for `split -C`:

```
split -C 100m -d data.tsv data.tsv.
```