# Best way to write multiple files from one large file?

Tags: c++, io

I have a very large file (13 gigs) that contains random 2d coordinates.

I must take these 2d coordinates and organize them into smaller blocks. (quadtree) Each one of these must be in a unique file. this could range from any where to 2 to 500 blocks.

It is a 32 bit application and am not able to fully load the 2d points.

1) Pre-generate each file stream and set buffer to 16k. Each file stream is stored in an array.
2) Iterate each point in 13 gig file.
3) Determine which block point belongs too.
4) Write point to the file stream corresponding to the block.
5) Once all points iterated, write headers and close all streams

This is extremely slow.... is there a better method? The only thing I can think of currently is to handle the buffer my self to utilize a bit more memory.

Comment: Going through 13 gigs of hard drive is not supposed to be fast anyway, let alone randomly writing them to other files.

Comment: Do you have to do this daily, or is it a once-off conversion? (In the latter case I'd make sure to write robust code and run it at night.)

Comment: 1) How about using `chunk`, [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18662202/unix-split-file-into-chunks-of-max-n-bytes-keeping-complete-lines]()? With chunking, you could also divide several files to several computers. 2) Fill the memory as much as possible and write everything down as blocks as big as possible. Just two ideas...

Comment: When you're switching between lots of different files, the disk will spend a lot of time seeking. You want to maximize the ratio of read/write to seek (either that or use a SSD where it doesn't matter). Don't rely on the file buffers but do buffering yourself, so that empty outputs aren't impacting your total buffering capacity, and write as much as you can to a single file at once.

Comment: 1) How about using `chunk`, [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18662202/unix-split-file-into-chunks-of-max-n-bytes-keeping-complete-lines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18662202/unix-split-file-into-chunks-of-max-n-bytes-keeping-complete-lines)? With chunking, you could also divide several files to several computers. 2) Fill the memory as much as possible and write everything down as blocks as big as possible. Just two ideas...

Comment: Try just copying the file and see how long that takes. This will give you an idea as to how efficient your program is. If it is a lot slower than the copy then you can probably improve it. If it is about the same, you are I/O bound and there is nothing to be done.

Comment: There is a program that does something very similar to mine, that does the process in 5 minutes, whereas my method explained above is taking 6 hours.

Comment: "Very similar" doesn't mean "the same". Let's do it like this. Make a sample 100MB file, and just process it in the straightforward way (you can load it all in memory and run your algorithm). This will be your reference running time. Now, multiply this time by 130, and you get the ideal running time you'd get if you could load 13GB into memory. How far is this from the time you're getting with your algorithm? If they're close, you won't be able to obtain much more (unless you go parallel, or on GPU, maybe).

Comment: Moreover, what are the conditions of your algorithm? Is your plane bounded? Are you using a static or adaptive quadtree? If static, do you know the number of subdivisions in advance or are you supposed to compute it from the input? Are the coordinates integers or floating points?

Comment: Does your solution need to be optimal under certain criteria?

Comment: it is a static quadtree. I know all of the subdivisions in advance.  the coordinates are floating points.  Giulio, very similar means the same 99% in my case. we are producing the same results from the same files.   I just need it to be as fast as the other software.   Reading through the files coordinates takes only 160 seconds.

Comment: How many output files?  Do the points in the output files need to be in any certain order?  When it runs for 6 hours, how much CPU is it using?  It is very important to only make one pass over the input file.

Comment: in the current test it is 122 files. the points in the file do not need to be in any certain order.  Currently using a single thread. hexacore cpu is at 8% cpu usage.   I have created my own buffer that writes 200,000 points at one time for each file. it has sped up the process a bit, would take roughly 4.5 hours at this rate.

Comment: Just foolproof question: did you enable compiler optimizations?

Comment: Also, what are the headers you're writing in step(5)?